# Show Regression with Arima Errors Equivalent Form of Differenced Variables

Tags: time-series, arima

How can you show that the regression $y_{t}=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{t}+\eta_t$ where $\eta_t$ is arima(1,1,1) is equivalent to $y'_t = \beta_1x'_{t}+\eta'_t$ where $\eta'_t=\phi_1\eta'_{t-1}+e_t$ and $'$ denotes a first difference?

Also, is it possible to construct a model where everything is differenced except $\eta_t$, as in $y'_t = \beta_1x'_{t}+\eta_t$ where $\eta_t=\phi_1\eta_{t-1}+e_t$ where $'$ denotes a first difference or does the error term always have to be differenced if y or x is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model for $y_{t-1}$ is written as:

$$
y_{t-1} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{t-1} + \eta_{t-1} \,.
$$

Thus, subtracting $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ gives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
y_t - y_{t-1} \equiv y_t' &=& 
\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + \eta_t -
(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{t-1} + \eta_{t-1}) \\
y_t' &=& \beta_1 x_t' + \eta_t' \,.
\end{eqnarray*}

The error term $\eta_t$ follows an ARMA(1,1,1), therefore by definition we have:

$$
\eta_t' = \phi \eta_{t-1}' + e_t + \theta e_{t-1} \,,
$$

where $e_t$, $t=1,2,...,n$, are independent and identically distributed 
with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ (white noise). I think you either missed the term $\theta e_{t-1}$ or you meant that $\eta_t$ follows an ARIMA(1,1,0).

Your second question could be related to a particular case of an  [autoregressive distributed lag model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag) (ADL). An ADL model of orders (1,1) can be defined as follows:

$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + \gamma_0 x_t + \gamma_1 x_{t-1} + u_t \,,
$$

where the error term $u_t$ can follow a stationary ARMA process.

Different restrictions on the parameters, which could be tested by means of 
an F-test, lead to models with different interpretations (e.g. partial 
adjustment in the dependent variable to changes in the explanatory variables or adaptive expectations). For details, you may see [Davidson and MacKinnon Section 13.4](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/ETM/) or [Econometric Methods with Applications in Business and Economics](http://global.oup.com/booksites/content/0199268010/) Section 7.5. (In a quick search, I did not find much information about this on wikipedia.)

If we set the restrictions $\beta_1 = 1$ and $\gamma_1 = -\gamma_0$, then we have a model in line with the model that you mention:

$$
y_t' = \beta_0 + \gamma_0 x_t' + u_t \,.
$$

In practice, if there is evidence of autocorrelation in the residuals of a fitted distributed lag model, then higher order lags of the dependent
variable ($y_{t-2}, y_{t-3},...$) are usually added to the right hand side of the model so that there is no serial correlation in the error term. That is, $u_t$ is usually considered not autocorrelated.

The last reference cited above discusses the effect and consequences of different structures in the error term. For example, they warn that in the presence of a moving average in the error term the ordinary least squares estimator is not consistent (a maximum likelihood estimator should be used in that case).

Comment: Very nice! And yes I meant to say arima (1,1,0). Your expanded answer was a nice bonus!